# IFrame log out service after page refreshing

Tags: html, iframe

I've got a website with an iframe in it with another website and every time user refreshes the page he becomes logged out. I thought this is because reloading clears cookies (with JSESSIONID cookie), but navigation on other sites doesn't logs the user out.

For example, if I click https://google.com link, then click back button, I will be still logged in in the website that is in iframe. But if I click refresh button, I will be logged out.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: My code is just `<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/my-url" ></iframe>`. I've just found that this issue appears only in chrome (I disabled 'block third party cookies flag'), in IE and firefox everything works good